# Neumorphic Design in flutter

Tags: flutter

How to achive Neumorphic design or UI in flutter

I am using this plugin which is `flutter_neumorphic 3.1.0` but got these error

> what am i doing wrong?

> How can i actually achive Neumorphic design in flutter

```
    Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
/C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_neumorphic-3.1.0/lib/src/widget/button.dart:200:14: Error: 'AnimatedScale' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/widgets/implicit_animations.dart' and 'package:flutter_neumorphic/src/widget/animation/animated_scale.dart'.
      child: AnimatedScale(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_neumorphic-3.1.0/lib/src/widget/switch.dart:167:20: Error: 'AnimatedScale' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/widgets/implicit_animations.dart' and 'package:flutter_neumorphic/src/widget/animation/animated_scale.dart'.
            child: AnimatedScale(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
3

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\Admin\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Admin\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

> I am sure that this happens because the AnimatedScale is called from different packages.
> how do i fix this?

Comment: It seems to be issue in the library you are using(library is not compatible with flutter 2.5.0), refer to this page it might help - [fullter_nuemorphic_issue](https://github.com/Idean/Flutter-Neumorphic/issues/239)

Comment: I referred this issue and helped me to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no issue with the libraries, The issue if of imports.

```
 'AnimatedScale' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/widgets/implicit_animations.dart' and 'package:flutter_neumorphic/src/widget/animation/animated_scale.dart'
```

Here as you can see it shows AnimatedScale is Imported from both the libraries.
Dart compiler wont know which AnimatedScale you want to use unless you specify it.

Simple Solution is

Step 1.

I am assuming you want to go for neumorphic
While importing libraries use
`import 'package:flutter_neumorphic/src/widget/animation/animated_scale.dart' as nmAnimatedScale`

Step 2.

Wherever you are using AnimatedScale replace it with `nmAnimatedScale.AnimatedScale( ......)`

Answer (score 1):

Please try this on your pubspec

```
  flutter_neumorphic:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/tsvillain/Flutter-Neumorphic.git
```

Answer (score 1):

update your package to flutter_neumorphic: ^3.2.0. I was also facing the same problem and got rid of this problem just after updating from 3.1.0 to 3.2.0. Hope, it will help you.

Comment: ok i will try that.